# Simplify a UML diagram by removing intermediary interfaces (created with ObjectAid)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, objectaid

In a project I have a rather complex class design with many interfaces and implementing classes. When I create an UML diagram it gets rather big. If I would be able to remove intermediary interfaces this would save a lot of space in the diagram.

As I am not very experienced with UML I have two questions:

- is removing intermediary interfaces "legitimate" in UML ?
- how could this be done with `ObjectAid UML Explorer` ?

Here is a simplified diagram that should show what I am talking about. If I were able to remove interface `Person` and only show the connection with class `PersonImpl` this would be sufficient.

This is what I would like to achieve (sorry, I did not have access to a better image manipulation program):

[image]

Comment: Without the interface Person, what will the connection between Family and PersonImpl become? Wouldn't you lose the original meaning of the UML diagram?

Comment: @Gosu perhaps I did not get your question right: I would like to connect Family and PersonImp directly because in this design PersonImpl is just an inplementation of the Person interface, nothing added / nothing removed.

Comment: Aren't you asking whether you can "remove intermediary interfaces in UML", which would be `Person` in this case?

Comment: @Gosu yes I am, I updated the image to better explain what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to use the lollipop notation:

[image: Lollipop]

Which is also called the [**Ball & Socket**](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BallAndSocket.html).

Comment: Do you happen to know how this can be done in ObjectAid (if not: ObjectAid creates the diagrams from source, so normally I don't draw them manually and have limited influence on how the diagram gets drawn) ? Does the "lollipop notation" have another name ? I did not find such an option in ObjectAid, perhaps I can find it with a different name.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know ObjectAid. Hopefully the edit from @Gosu will help. Socket is the required interface and shown as a half circle while the above is a provided interface.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that would be a useful or legitimate diagram. Unless `Family` is already aware of `PersonImpl` (which usually I'd expect it not to be), there's no association to be drawn, there's no direct relationship between the two types.